# Could we always find a line to intersect transversally with a given compact manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-topology

This problem may be an embarrassing one, but I could not prove it even for the $1$ dimensional case. Here is the problem:

> **Question 1.** $M$ is a compact $n$-dimensional smooth manifold in $R^{n+1}$. Take a point $p\notin M$. Prove there is always a line $l_p$ pass $p$ and $l_p\cap M\neq \emptyset$, and $l_p$ intersect transversally with $M$.

You can naturally generalise it to:

> **Question 2.**  $M$ is a compact $n$-dimensional smooth manifold in $R^{n+m}$. Take a point $p\notin M$. Prove $\forall 1\leq k\leq m$, there is always a hyperplane $P_p, dim(P_p)=k$ pass $p$ and $P_p\cap M\neq \emptyset$, and $P_p$ intersect transversally with $M$.

Thanking for Piotr pointing out, assume "transverse" means "the tangent spaces intersect only at 0".

We focus on question 1 for simplicity.

Even in $1$ dimension it is not easy at least for me, **warning**: a line $l$ pass $p$ may be intersect $M$ at several points combine a set $A_l$, $A_l$ could be finite, countable or even it is not countable (consider $M$ is induced by a smooth function for which the zeros set is Cantor set.)... And if there is one point $a\in A_l$, $l$ is tangent with the tangent line of $M$ at $a$, then $l$ is not intersect transversally with $M$.

**My attempt**: 
I could use a dimensional argument and Sard's theorem to establish a similar result but instead of a fix point $p$, we prove for generic point in $R^{n+1}$ which is not in $M$ we can choose such a line.

So it seems reasonable to develop the dimensional technique to attach the question 1, in 1 dimensional, it will relate to investigate the ordinary differential equation:
$$\frac{f(x)-b}{x-a}=f'(x)$$
Where $p=(a,b)$, $M$ have a parameterization $M=\{x,f(x)\}$. If there is a counterexample for the question 1, then there is another solution which satisfied the ODE in the sense:

At least for every line $l$ there is a intersection point $a_l\in l\cap M$, $f$ satisfied ODE at $a_l$.

This is just like the uniqueness of the solution of such a ODE is destroyed at some subspace of a line which has some special linear structure, I do not know if this point of view will be helpful.

I will appreciate for any useful answers and comments.

Comment: I assume "transitive" means "transversally".

Comment: It depends a bit on what exactly you mean by a "smooth manifold". Clearly a straight open interval on the plane and a point on the extension of that interval isn't something you are interested in. So, what exactly do you assume to exclude such stupid configurations?

Comment: @fedja, sorry I forget to assume $M$ is compact, thanks! This is not mean I am not interested in whether this kind of type is true for not compact case, but I could not describe very exactly what condition will make this type of result to be true (it seem it is necessary to assume $M$ is not a "cone" central at $p$ to make this result to be true), anyway. Thanks!

Comment: One obvious approach would be this: if a line $\ell$ through $p$ is not transversal to $M$, then the area of $M$ in the cone of some small aperture $\varepsilon>0$ vastly exceeds $\varepsilon^n$. So if the projection of $M$ to the sphere centered at $p$ has positive area, you run into a contradiction immediately (well, with some minimally intelligent  use of either covering lemmas or uniform bounds on smoothness, whichever you like more).

Comment: @Huxiyu P.S. Nothing to be embarrased about, by the way. I can tell you much more shameful examples of *my own* mathematical blindness and I suspect the other people can do it too if you find a way to open them up :-)

Comment: @fedja, appreciate! This is a very clever argument! Use this argument we can easily prove the projection area of $M$ to $S^{n}$ have Hausdorff $n$ volume 0, if we could proved it is exactly have hausdorff dimension $\leq n-1$, then combine with sard's theorem we will arrive at a proof, but I do not know how to use your method to proof after the projection the image's hausdorff dimension $\leq n-1$,  I was wondering may you explain it more precisely or you have another way to establish the result?

Comment: The only way to have the projection that small is to have the normal to the manifold perpendicular to the direction to $p$ at *every* point of $M$, which, for all practical purposes means that stupid cone-like structure that has to be excluded by formulating the assumptions clearly (closed interval is compact, say, but has boundary, so should we say "compact without boundary"? That will work because then at the point of $M$ closest to $p$ the normal is parallel to the direction to $p$ and you already get an open set in the radial projection)

Comment: And you do not need Hausdorff projection of dimension $n-1$ and Sard. Just do the trivial area count!

Comment: Very clever argument! I have thought  to use the nearest or the most far point of $M$ to $p$ to get some information, but I loss the most important piece of jigsaw, which is just to consider the volume and consider the projection to $S_n$ will lead to a contradiction, I could image this argument must be very effective at a lot of place, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## For the codimension 1 case.

#### Using Thom transversality theorem.

Consider the maps $f_s:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ parametrized by $s \in S^{n-1}$ and given by $f_s(t) = p + t \cdot s$. The map $F(s,t) = f_s(t)$, $F:S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is clearly transverse to $M$, thus Thom's transversality says that $f_s$ is transverse to $M$ for almost all $s$. Now it suffices to prove that for an open set in $S^{n-1}$, the line given by $f_s$ intersects $M$. Proven below.

#### Using Sard's theorem directly.

Thom's transversality is usually proven using Sard's theorem. Here is the idea.

Consider the projection $\Pi:\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\}\to S^{n-1}_p$ onto a sphere centered at $p$. A line $l_p$ through $p$ intersects $M$ transversally if the two points $l_p \cap S^{n-1}_p$ are regular values of $\Pi$ (indeed, the critical points of $\Pi$ are exactly the points $x \in M$ at which the normal $\vec n_x$ is perpendicular to the radial direction (with respect to $p$)). By Sard's theorem, the set of regular values is dense in $S^{n-1}_p$.

We need to choose any point $s$ on the sphere for which both $s$ and $-s$ are regular values, and the line $f_s$ through $p$ and $s$ actually intersects $M$. It suffices to prove that the set of points $s$ for which this line intersects $M$ contains an open set. We could now use the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem and we would be done, but we can do it more directly (and in a way that seems to generalize).

#### The set of points $s \in S$ for which $f_s$ intersects $s$ has nonempty interior.

For each point $q \notin M$ the projection $\Pi:M \to S_{q,\varepsilon_q}^{n-1}$ onto the sphere centered at $q$, of radius $\varepsilon_q$ small enough so that the sphere does not intersect $M$, has some (topological) degree $d_q$. It is easy to check that if one takes any point $x \in M$ and considers the points $x \pm \delta \vec n_x$ for small $\delta$, the degrees of the corresponding maps differ by $1$. It follows that we can find a point $q$ for which $d_q \neq d_p$, which guarantees that for every point $q'$ in a small open ball $B$ around $q$ (all these points have same degree $d_q$), the line joining $p$ and $q'$ intersects $M$. Projection of $B$ on $S_p^{n-1}$ is an open set which we sought.

## For the general case (partial solution).

I think a similar reasoning should work, however, notice that for $k < m$ we cannot make $P_p$ intersect transversally with $M$ because of dimensional reasons: the dimensions of $M$ and $P_p$ don't add up to at least $n+m$. Recall that transversality implies  Thus, either (1) you want to consider $k \geq m$, or (2) define "transversal intersection" for such manifolds saying that the tangent spaces have to intersect at an empty set.

Also, for $k>n$ we can just take any plane $P_p$ which works for $k=m$ and just extend it to a $k$-dimensional plane.

#### Assuming $k = m$.

A similar reasoning should work for $f_s:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ with $s = (s_1, \ldots, s_m)$ going over all families of pairwise perpendicular unit vectors, and $f_s(t_1,\ldots,t_m) = p+\sum_{j=1}^m t_i \cdot s_i$. Thom's transversality says that for almost all choices of $s$, the plane $f_s$ is transverse to $M$.

#### The nonempty interior issue.

The only thing left is to prove that the set of $s$ for which the intersection is nonempty has nonempty interior. Last time we proved that there is a zero-dimensional sphere containing $p$, namely $\{p,q\}$, which has nonzero linking number with $M$, and by deforming if to spheres $\{p,q'\}$ and taking lines through pairs $p,q'$, we got an open set of parameters for which the line intersects $M$.

Here should be able to do a similar trick by finding a $m-1$-dimensional sphere with nonzero linking number with $M$. The ball that bounds that sphere has to intersect $M$, thus the plane $P$ containing the sphere has to intersect $M$. By perturbing the sphere we get spheres with the same linking numbers, and get all the planes that lie in a neighbourhood of $P$; in particular, we get an open set of parameters $s$ for which $f_s$ intersects $M$.

Well, we don't actually need a *round* sphere, but we do need a *smooth* sphere that lies in a $m$-dimensional plane. There's some trickery needed to do this, but I am sure something like this can be done.

Maybe somebody else can do it better?

#### For $k<m$

I don't really know how to attack this case, assuming "transverse" means "the tangent spaces intersect only at $0$".

**Update (thanks to Fan Zheng):**
This follows from the $k=m$ case. Take any $m$-plane $P$ that intersects $M$ and does it transversally. Then, any $k$-plane inside $P$ intersects $M$ "transversally" in the above sense. We choose any $k$-plane $\tilde P \subset P$ which contains both $p$ and any point $x \in P \cap M$, and we're done.

Comment: Appreciate! this is a excellent answer! Sorry, for $k<m$ case the transverse us just mean "the tangent spaces intersect only at 0", I have corrected it. Would it be true that $k<m$ case is the directly result of $k=m$ case? By the way, I thought the area trick which is mentioned by fedja  still effective, we can use the area trick to proof question 2 which lead to another proof. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Huxiyu If you define transversality this way, then the $k<m$ case is indeed a consequence of the $k=m$ case.